# Azure Dev-ops: NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source - Same Organization, different projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I’m new to using Azure Dev-ops pipelines.
I’m trying to build a simple .NET console app using the pipelines.

So, on the same organization, we have two projects. Project A has a Nuget feed in it’s artifacts. And Project B has a .NET solution that references a Nuget package in A.

In the YML file I added A’s feed using the given GUI:

```
steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetAuthenticate@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
  command: 'restore'
  restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
  feedsToUse: 'select'
  vstsFeed: '[generated vsts feed]'
```

And when I run the pipeline I always get the error in Nuget restore -
`##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[Organization Name]/[generated vsts feed project part]/_packaging/[generated vsts feed package part]/nuget/v3/index.json.`

The troubleshooting I already tried that I found online:

1. Unchecked “Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines” in A.
2. Added “[B] Build Service (Organization)” to “Build Administrator” group in A’s permissions in its project settings
3. Added “[B] Build  Service (Organization)” to the relevant feed in A artifact settings -> Permission as “Contributor”

I'll be glad to get some help with that.